# How Come Height Isn't Defined

Tags: java, image, image-processing, height, width

I'm working on a game in java. My Background class needs a width and height but it still doesn't recognise them.

```
package TileMap;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import main.GamePanel;

public class Background {

private BufferedImage image;
private int width;

private double x;
private double y;
private double dx;
private double dy;

private double moveScale;

public Background(String s, double ms) {

        try {
                image = ImageIO.read(
                        getClass().getResourceAsStream(s)
                );
                width = image.getWidth(); 
                height = image.getHeight(); 
                moveScale = ms;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public void setPosition(double x, double y) {
        this.x = (x * moveScale); 
        this.y = (y * moveScale);
        fixPosition(); 
}

public void setVector(double dx, double dy) {
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
}

public void update() {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        fixPosition(); 
}


private void fixPosition() {
        while(x <= -width) x += width;
        while(x >= width) x -= width;
        while(y <= -height) y += height;
        while(y >= height) y -= height;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

        g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);

        if(x < 0) {
                g.drawImage(
                        image,
                        (int)x + GamePanel.WIDTH,
                        (int)y,
                        null
                );
        }
        if(x > 0) {
                g.drawImage(
                        image,
                        (int)x - GamePanel.WIDTH,
                        (int)y,
                        null
                );
        }
}

}
```

`image.getHeight` gives me an error saying "Height Can not be resolved into a variable" although `image.getWidth` is not. Could somebody tell me what is the issue with my code?

Comment: you didnt define `height`. end of..

Answer (score 3):

You've defined `width` but don't seem to have defined the `height` variable (as an int). Do so:

```
private int height;
```